# One Time Bulk Node Creation

Tags: 8

I have Drupal 8 site I need to migrate a bunch of data into from a different CMS.  What I'd like to do is write a basic SQL query and iterate through the results, creating a new node for each returned row.

Since it's a one time thing - do I need to write a full module for this - or can I just hook into drupal some other way (like through the main index.php file) and do the node::create([]) $node->save() stuff from within there?

Never done something like this before - and looking for the easiest way.  Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Consider a custom Drupal Console command. https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/extending/creating-custom-commands.html or Migrate https://www.drupal.org/node/2127611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a "full" module for this, you can do this with two files and a few lines of code:

modules/myimport/myimport.info.yml:

```
name: myimport
description: 'My import module'
core: 8.x
version: 8.x-1.x-dev
type: module
```

modules/myimport/myimport.module:

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
function import_stuff() {
  // fetch data
  foreach ( $data as $row ) {
    $node = node::create([]);
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

You can start the import from anywhere in drupal or from the command line with drush:

```
drush ev 'import_stuff()'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module - You can check the doc [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/feeds).
2. Export the content from source into csv or json. On the target (D8) either you can use Migrate module to handle the migration but requires custom coding.
3. Create a json endpoint that will expose the content and in your target (D8) server consume that endpoint. You can then get the content by using `Guzzle`.

Example...

```
$request = Drupal::httpClient()->get($url);
```

See [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1862446) for more info.

**P.S:** I have no experience building with D8 yet but my suggestions above I guess is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a bunch of data, it's probably best to use the migrate module.

I've recently a migration with migrate_plus, which comes with a migrate_example module you can copy.  There's a yml file and a class for BeerNode that you can pretty much copy.

Then, set up your other database in settings.php:

```
$databases['example_other_db']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'lifecenter',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Then, you can specify the source in the yml file for your importer.

```
  source:
    key: example_other_db
```

Then you basically map the fields to custom keys within your migrate class (see BeerNode.php in migrate_example module)

Here's some examples from my recent migration:

```
  field_copyright_year: copyright
  field_isbn: ISBN
  field_volume: volume
  field_pages_length: pagesLength
  field_pub_title: bookJournalMagazineTitle
  field_edition: edition
  field_short_place: placePublished
  field_shelf_code: callNumber
```

If you need something complex like an address field you can build it in your class, so the custom key is an array that matches what addressfield expects.  There's a prepareRow function where you can do other queries

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {

    $row->setSourceProperty('companyName', $this->cleanString($row->getSourceProperty('companyName')));

    $address = [
      "langcode" => "EN",
      "country_code" => "US",
      "administrative_area" => "US-" . $row->getSourceProperty('state'),
      "locality" => $row->getSourceProperty('city'),
      "dependent_locality" => NULL,
      "postal_code" => $this->cleanString($row->getSourceProperty('zip')),
      "sorting_code" => NULL,
      "address_line1" => $row->getSourceProperty('address1'),
      "address_line2" => $row->getSourceProperty('address2'),
      "organization" => $row->getSourceProperty('companyName'),
    ];

    $row->setSourceProperty('address', $address);

    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
```

Then you run the migration from the command line.

1) run "drush ms" and make sure it lists your migration

2) run "drush mi example_migrate_machinename"

3) to pause import, do "drush mst example_migrate_machinename"

4) for other commands you can run " drush | grep migrate"